# No output (send part) on BizTalk pipeline

Tags: biztalk, flat-file, disassembly, biztalk-pipelines

I have built a flatfile schema with the flatfile schema wizard.
The schema is valid and I could successfully validate my test instance against the schema.(So the XML file was created correctly).

But when I put my test flat file into a receive location that uses a flatfile disassembler pipeline, nothing happens after the receive location has picked up the message (the logical receive port is bounded to an orchestration)
In the BizTalk Admin Console I only see in the tracked message events from the pipeline that the message has been received. But not sent.

Maybe some of you already had a similar issue and could help me here.

**Tracked message events in the pipeline**

[image]

Comment: Sent...where do you expect it to go?

Comment: I expect a similar EventType entry in the BT admin console that describes the Send part containing the outbound XML file. But as listed above I can only only see the receive part containing the original flat file. And if there is an error I expect at least an event log entry. But both did not appear.

Comment: And you don't have any suspended instances? Your orchestration is running?

Comment: One possible cause is the Disassembler produces no output.  BTW, the Receive and Send Event Type you see here are from the Pipeline perspective, not the entire system.

Comment: You are right it is only from a pipeline perspective. But I don't see any other entries in the BT Admin Console. Neither suspended and running instances nor terminated ones. And in case no output will be produced wouldn't I get an error message? And as I have validated the flat file against my flat file schema, I normally expect an output, don't I? 
Orchestration is running as well. Otherwise I expect a "message could not be routed" or some other event log entry

Comment: OK. I have tested the FlatFileDisassembler with FFDasm.exe in the Pipeline Tools. And as already mentioned by John, it does not produce any output. I have removed the header spec shcema in the pipeline properties and at least now the message will be processed. So it must be something with the header schema. I will provide the error after I have found it. Thanks to all at the moment. I appreciate your work!!!

Answer (score 0):

So. The issue was a wrong declared header schema. I have rebuild it and after that it was working fine.
I have recognized the issue by removing the header schema from the pipeline properties and trigger a new process. At this time the message was created correctly (but with the header line due to a missing header schema that would prevent that line).

Thanks to all who helped here!